# Haskell - No instance for (Num (Integer -> Integer)) for function with custom data type

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have a custom data type `Flist` containing functions. In the next step I would like to use the `Flist myFunctions` in `apply`.

**Note**: This is an exercise, so I have to use a custom list

```
data Flist a = Nil | Cons (a -> a) (Flist a)

myFunctions :: Flist (Integer -> Integer)
myFunctions = (Cons (\y x -> x + 1) ( Cons (\x w -> w + 1) (Nil)))

apply :: Flist (a -> a) -> b -> b
apply Nil b         = b
apply (f `Cons` xs) b = apply xs (f b)
```

The call should look like that: `apply myFunctions 1` returns `3`

I get the error:

> - No instance for (Num (Integer -> Integer))
>         arising from the literal `2'
>         (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
>
>   - In the second argument of 'apply', namely '2'
>       In the expression: apply myFunctions 2
>       In an equation for 'it': it = apply myFunctions 2

**Question**: I do not see my mistake. Why should I have applied not enough arguments to the function? I pass a Flist with functions that get an Int and return an Int. Additionally another Int is passed and that should be it. What is still missing here?

Comment: Unless this is an exercise, normals lists can hold functions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, I have to use my custom list

Comment: Hint: if `Flist a` contains `a -> a` functions, what does `Flist (x->y)` contain? Regardless... you shouldn't have run into the error you quote, you should have earlier run into a clearer to understand error when compiling `apply`. Let me guess: you didn't compile it with the type signature? Bad idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

You have

```
data Flist a = Nil | Cons (a -> a) (Flist a)
--         ^               ^^^^^^
```

So if you have a function `f :: Integer -> Integer`, then `Cons f Nil` has type `Flist Integer`, not `Flist (Integer -> Integer)`.

In fact, a `Flist (Integer -> Integer)` would be a list of functions of type `(Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)`.

That means `myFunctions :: Flist (Integer -> Integer)` has the wrong type. If you fix that, you'll discover that the code for it isn't quite right either.

---

Then there's `apply :: Flist (a -> a) -> b -> b`. This is another instance of the above problem (one layer of "function-ness" too many). Changing that to `apply :: Flist a -> b -> b` reveals another problem: You do `(f b)` where `f :: a -> a` and `b :: b`. But `a` and `b` are different type variables and (at least potentially) different. To allow this function application, it would have to be `apply :: Flist a -> a -> a`.

Comment: if I change `myFunctions :: Flist (Integer -> Integer) ` to `myFunctions :: Flist Integer ` I get the error:  * Couldn't match type `Integer -> Integer' with `Integer'
      Expected type: Flist Integer
        Actual type: Flist (Integer -> Integer)

If I understand you correct, I have to change it that way?

Comment: @jublikon You need to remove the unused `y` and `x` arguments from your functions.